# What is the pattern of the first Timestamp returned by the DatetimeIndexResampler object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time Series like this:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['01:55:00', '02:25:00', '03:20:00', '02:35:00'])
ts = Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=idx)
ts

2019-04-20 01:55:00    1
2019-04-20 02:25:00    2
2019-04-20 03:20:00    3
2019-04-20 02:35:00    4
dtype: int64
```

When I use `resample` function with the parameter '2T',the `groups` dict like this:

```
r = ts.resample('2T')
r.groups

{Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:54:00', freq='2T'): 1,
 Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:56:00', freq='2T'): 1,
 ...
}
```

The first Timestamp is '01:54:00',and when I change the parameter, the first Timestamp changes too.

```
r = ts.resample('5T')
r.groups

{Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:55:00', freq='5T'): 1,
 Timestamp('2019-04-20 02:00:00', freq='5T'): 1,
 ...
}

r = ts.resample('15T')
r.groups
{Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:45:00', freq='15T'): 1,
 Timestamp('2019-04-20 02:00:00', freq='15T'): 1,
 ...
}
```

I dont't know what is the rule.I have searched the documentation of Pandas and googled,But didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Pandas did something complicated to the first&last Timestamp.In this case,the simplified code like this:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
first = pd.Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:55:00')
offset = to_offset('35T')
start_day_nanos = first.normalize().value
foffset = (first.value - start_day_nanos) % offset.nanos
fresult = first.value - foffset
pd.Timestamp(fresult)

Timestamp('2019-04-20 01:45:00')
```